# Ask about global maximum and global minimum?

Tags: maxima-minima

The temperature distribution in a metal rod given by the following function of the position $x \in \mathbb{R}$: $$T(x) = \frac{1 + 2x}{2 + x^2}$$

What is the maximal and minimal temperature in the metal rod?

$T'(x) = 0$ when $x = 1$ or $x = -2$. But I can't calculate the global maximum and global minimum because $T(x)$ does not belong to any intervals? Am I correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Where is the given interval for that function?

Comment: Try to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question the next time.

Comment: Thanks. Actually there are no any intervals in the question. That's why I am confused.

Comment: Try to draw this function with the help of derivative...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many things become clearer when you graph the function.

[image]

\begin{align}
   \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1 + 2x}{2 + x^2}\right) &= 0 \\
   \dfrac{-2(x^2 + x - 2)}{(x^2+2)^2} &= 0 \\
   x^2 + x - 2 &= 0 \\
   (x+2)(x-1) &= 0 \\
   x &\in \{-2, 1\}
\end{align}

Note that $$\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \frac{1 + 2x}{2 + x^2} = 0$$.

The max value is at $T(1)=1$ and the min value is at $T(-2)=-\dfrac 12.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: I have got $$f_{max}=1$$ at $$x=1$$

$$f_{min}=-\frac{1}{2}$$ at $$x=-2$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your work on the derivative is correct (I haven't checked), since $T$ is continuous:
\begin{align}
T(1)&=1\\
T(-2)&=-\frac{1}{2}\\
T(-\infty)&=T(+\infty)=0
\end{align}

So there you have: global max at $x=1$ and global min at $x=-2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot francescop21. It really helps.